# Change Cell Color Based on Two Cell's Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for an onEdit google spreadsheet script to change the background of a cell in column C to be red if column C does not contain "x" and if column R does contain "DS".

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a link to a dummy set of data so we have a little more clarity about what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the colour changing is independent from one another, if so then something like the below will work. If not then it's simply adjustable.

```
function onEdit(){
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var val = cell.getValue();
  Logger.log(col);
  if(col == 3){
    val != "x" ? cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0) : cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
  } else if (col == 18){
    val != "DS" ? cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0) : cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
```